# How Core Data interacts with Managed Objects?

Tags: swift, core-data

Here is my test code and I can't really understand why `print("db2: \(prod)")` writes that my element has attribute `belok = 10000`. But I didn't save the context, so in DB there is no changes, it's ok. I'm trying to understand how interact DB and my array `arrDBProducts`.

```
var arrDBProducts: [DB_Product]

    func test() {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<DB_Product> = DB_Product.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let prods = try CoreDB.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for prod in prods {
            print("db1: \(prod)")
        }
    }
    catch {}

    arrDBProducts[0].belok = 10000
    print("array: \(arrDBProducts)")

    let fetchRequest2: NSFetchRequest<DB_Product> = DB_Product.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let prods = try CoreDB.context.fetch(fetchRequest2)
        for prod in prods {
            print("db2: \(prod)")
        }
    }
    catch {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are didn't save the context, so once you will close and open your app or if you will try to access it from another context - you will not see that changes.

But, while you are working in one context - your changes will exist in it until context will be released.

Comment: Yes, I see, I just try to understand why the data in my CoreDB.context is touched when I change it in array like this: arrDBProducts[0].belok = 10000

Comment: @АлександрГинько because, as I can see from your code, all object in your ` arrDBProducts` array exist in `CoreDB.context` context. So all changes would exist in `that context`, until that context will not be released or until you will not call `rollback` function on this `context`